# Any solution to choreograher error "xxx frames skipped.Main thread might be doing to much work" uploading camera image from android phone to server?

Tags: php, android, matlab

ANDROID CODE:

```
/*image is clicked using hardware camera of android phone and downsized and image is compressed for fast transmission to server*            
/*image is sent to server using Post*/
httpPost    = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.5:80/EqSolverProcessWritten.php");
```

SERVER CODE:

```
    /* Get input and configuration parameters */
    $bData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    /* Save the uploaded jpg image to file */
    file_put_contents( upload/image.jpg, $bData);
    ?>
```

Comment: *"ANDROID CODE:"* nope. "Any solution", yes move heavy operations to the background. Other than that, it's hard to say without seeing your code. Investigate when this is happening and see what can be moved off of the main thread

Comment: @codeMagic **ANDROID CODE**

Comment: You should not be doing network I/O on the main application thread.

Comment: I resolved the problem using async threads and removed the load from main thread. Now the image is getting transferred from my Android device to laptop but the when I try to open the uploaded image it says"Windows photo viewer can't display this picture because the file is empty".how do I resolve this.